# Retrieving Direct Message image from Twitter using Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm making a script that retrieving image that sent by someone on Direct Message.
I need to take the media URL to download the image (I'll make the code for download the image later)

This the code for retrieving the image

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication OK")
except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
    print("Error during authentication :", e.message[0]['code'])

messages = api.list_direct_messages(count=3)

for message in reversed(messages):
    sender_id = message.message_create["sender_id"]
    recipient_id = message.message_create["target"]["recipient_id"]
    text = message.message_create["message_data"]["text"]
    sender_url = message.message_create["message_data"]["attachment"]

checkString = text.find("post!")

if int(recipient_id) == int(myUserID):   
    if checkString == -1:
        userText = "Please put post! in the beginning of your tweet"
        for media in sender_url:
            urlImage = media.media["media_url_https"]

        print("LINK :", urlImage)       
        print(f"Message does not contain post!, message : {text}")
        try:
            api.send_direct_message(sender_id, userText)
        except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
            print("Error during send direct message :", e.message[0]['code'])
    else:
        print(f"Message contain post!, message : {text}")
        try:
            api.update_status(text)
            print("Tweet Success")
        except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
            print("Error during post tweet :", e.message[0]['code'])
```

but the result is

```
sender_url = message.message_create["message_data"]["attachment"]
KeyError: 'attachment'
```

the real result must be

```
LINK: https://p.twimg.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
the main problem is I just want to get the media URL from the media that received from Direct message

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure all of the past three DMs have images/attachments?

Comment: Yes, I give "terms" for sender of Direct Message to send Direct Message with images.

Comment: Are you saying you send a DM? If so, does that DM also include an image/attachment? The three most recent DMs, including sent DMs, will be returned.

Comment: I mean, someone is sending me a DM that is attached with an image, and using this code, I'll get the image and the text of DM. But the problem is I can't get the media_url that I'll use to download the image to my local, and then I will post the image that I downloaded and the text that I received from someone.

Comment: With `api.list_direct_messages(count=3)` you're retrieving the three most recent DMs, and then you're iterating through all three. Again, are you sure *all three* have images/attachments?